# Bias of an estimator

Tags: statistics

There's a sample $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n$ from distribution $N(\mu ,\sigma^2 )$, where both parameters are unknown. For evaluating $\sigma^2$, there's
$$\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2$$
Prove that evaluation is asymptotically unbiased.

I could use some help with this problem.

Comment: I could use some help too.

Answer (score 0):

$E(s^2)=E\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2  \right]=\frac{1}{n}\cdot E\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\overline x)^2  \right]$

Just expand $(x_i-\overline x)^2 $.

Hint: $  \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=n\cdot \overline x$

Edit: The "n" has been inserted.

greetings,

calculus

Comment: You're missing an $n$ in your hint.

Comment: @hejseb Thank you for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What happens to your estimator as $n\to \infty$? For example
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n} \longrightarrow^p \quad ?
$$
Use an appropriate theorem to show asymptotic unbiasedness.